# What's the quickest way to find matches in two arrays containing objects in Powershell?

Tags: arrays, object, powershell, active-directory

I have a number of objects inside two arrays.  Each object has the same properties.

Example object:

```
$obj1 = New-Object System.Object;
$obj1 | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name FirstName 'George'; 
$obj1 | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name LastName 'Banks';
$obj1 | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name EmployeeID '1903';
```

Arrays:

```
$array1 = @($obj1,$obj2,$obj3);
$array2 = @($obj5,$obj3,$obj9);
```

My goal is to match each object in each array in a 1:1 relationship based on two factors; matching EmployeeID or if the EmployeeID is not populated then match on FirstName,LastName combination.

For example, let's say I have the following condition:

```
$obj1 = New-Object System.Object;
$obj1 | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name FirstName 'George'; 
$obj1 | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name LastName 'Banks';
$obj1 | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name EmployeeID '1903'; 

$obj2 = New-Object System.Object;
$obj2 | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name FirstName 'Paul'; 
$obj2 | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name LastName 'Newman';
$obj2 | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name EmployeeID '567';

$obj3 = New-Object System.Object;
$obj3 | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name FirstName 'George'; 
$obj3 | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name LastName 'Banks';
$obj3 | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name EmployeeID '1903'; 

$obj4 = New-Object System.Object;
$obj4 | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name FirstName 'Paul'; 
$obj4 | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name LastName 'Newman';
$obj4 | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name EmployeeID '';

$array1 = @($obj1,$obj2);
$array2 = @($obj3,$obj4);
```

In this example, I can match George Banks on his EmployeeID because it exists in both arrays.  However, Paul Newman doesn't have an EmployeeID populated in $array2 so I need to match him based on his FirstName/LastName combination.

Ultimately, I'd like to get an array output like this that merges all of each object's properties together into a single object.

```
$obj1.FirstName = 'George'
$obj1.LastName = 'Banks'
$obj1.EmployeeID = '1903'
$obj2.FirstName = 'Paul';
$obj2.LastName = 'Newman';
$obj2.EmployeeID = '567'

$aOutput = @($obj1,$obj2);
```

Real world reason I'm doing this is two reasons.

1. I have a spreadsheet of employees with FirstName,LastName,EmployeeID,Department.  In Active Directory, only FirstName and LastName are typically populated.  I want to take the data in the spreadsheet and populate that user's Active Directory user account with the missing data.
2. We have thousands of Active Directory user accounts that are not specifically assigned to an actual employee and currently no way to know.  I need this script to find a way to match an actual employee with their respective Active Directory user account so we can mark that.  Once marked, that user account will not be susceptible to removal if that user account hasn't authenticated in 60 days.

Comment: I think there's a copy-and-paste error in the setup for $obj3 in the example.  This line:  `$obj2 | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name EmployeeID '1903';` should refer to $obj3 instead of $obj2.  I would have edited it, but the interface requires a change to at least 6 characters.

Comment: You might want to adjust your example, since your desired output is the same as your input, i.e. obj1 and obj2 don't change.  While this is valid based on the input, it doesn't illustrate what a change would look like.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this.  This code checks to see if the employee IDs match OR if the concatenation of first name and last name match.  If so, it then checks each field in the object in array 1 to see if it's empty.  If it is, then it copies the contents of the corresponding field in the matched object in array 2.

```
foreach ($employee1 in $array1) { 
    foreach ($employee2 in $array2) {
        if( ($employee1.EmployeeID -eq $employee2.EmployeeID) -or 
            ("$($employee1.FirstName)$($employee1.LastName)" -eq "$($employee2.FirstName)$($employee2.LastName)")) {
            if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($employee1.FirstName)) {
                $employee1.FirstName = $employee2.FirstName
            } elseif ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($employee1.LastName)) {
                $employee1.LastName = $employee2.LastName
            } elseif ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($employee1.EmployeeID)) {
                $employee1.EmployeeID = $employee2.EmployeeID
            }       
        } 
    } 
}
```

A few things to consider:

1. You may want to create a new set of objects, do a sanity check of the changes, then copy over your original objects.
2. This code will break if you have entries for different people that share first name and last name.
3. This code doesn't consider the case where corresponding fields are both empty.

Answer (score -1):

After a lot of trial and tribulation I eventually got it.  What I ended up doing was transferring all object properties into a regex string and then matching based on that.